# Changing Atoms autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

Okay. So Atom installs `autocomplete-plus` by default. Its quite helpful when I write code, but for example it writes `std::cout << "/* message */" << '\n';` when I write `cout`, but I want it to write `std::cout << "/* message */" << std::endl`, cause there is a difference between those two, the second one flushes the buffer. How can I make it work my way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify your desired autocomplete behavior within your snippets.cson file.

1. Open snippets.cson by going to Edit -> Snippets...
2. Add the following to the file:

```
        '.source.c':
          'cout':
            'prefix': 'cout'
            'body': 'std::cout << "/* ${1:message} */" << std::endl$2'
```

The first line selects which grammar to activate on (C in this case, you can find more [here](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/wiki/Autocomplete-Providers)).
The second line is a description of the snippet; it could be anything.
The third line (prefix) specifies what you would have to type in a C file for the snippet to work.

In this example, typing `cout` in a C file while show the description in the autocomplete menu and allow for tab-completion. The last line specifies what the snippet should expand to. Use the `$` syntax to specify tab ordering.

Note, you can specify default values for tab stops within the snippet using syntax like `${1:message}`. In this case, the snippet will expand and automatically select the text `message` for rapid editing. Hitting tab again will proceed to tab stop 2, or the end of the line.

Note, you can specify any number of additional snippets for each grammar, as in:

```
    '.source.c':
      'cout':
        'prefix': 'cout'
        'body': 'std::cout << "/* ${1:message} */" << std::endl$2'
      'Another snippet description':
        'prefix': 'something'
        'body': 'Something is ${1:nice}'
```

Comment: Jesus, dude, you rock! Thanks!

Comment: And by the way, can I somewhere see how the other ones are written? Just to copy the example and change it a little bit? (cuz I don't really see how can I write it for a `for loop`

Comment: In Atom, all of the C related snippets are contained in the `language-c` package. If you go to Settings -> Packages -> `language-c` and scroll down, you will see all of the snippets. I forgot to mention that you can write multi-line snippets as well (described at the bottom of [this page](https://atom.io/packages/snippets))